# How to choose one element based on its probability?

Tags: matlab, probability, stochastic-process

Let's say I have a vector containing N elements, each being its probability. For example, `v = [0.01 0.01 0.09 0.82 0.07]`

So I want a function `f(v)` that returns 4 at 82% of the time, 3 at 9% of the time etc.

The input vector v is always normalized so that `sum(v) = 1`, this can be a simplification.

How can I implement this probabilistic function in MATLAB? Or maybe there is a built-in function for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do **NOT** have the statistics toolbox (otherwise see [Stewie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26470768/2180721)) derive the empirical cdf and then use [inverse sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling):

```
% Numbers of draws
N = 1e3; 
% Sample a uniform in (0, 1)
x = rand(N,1);

% Empirical cdf
ecdf = cumsum([0, v]);

% Inverse sampling/binning 
[counts, bin] = histc(x,ecdf);
```

where `bin` maps directly to `v`. So, if you have a generic set of values `y` with probabilitites `v`, you should take:

```
out = y(bin);
```

Note, as the number of draws `N` increases, we get a better approximation of the probabilities:

```
counts(end) = []; % Discard last bucket x==1
counts./sum(counts)
```

The function can be:

```
function [x, counts] = mysample(prob, val, N)
if nargin < 2 || isempty(val), val = 1:numel(prob); end
if nargin < 3 || isempty(N),   N   = 1;             end 

[counts, bin] = histc(rand(N,1), cumsum([0, prob(:)']));
x = val(bin);

end
```

Answer (score 4):

If you have the statistic toolbox, you can use [`randsample`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/stats/randsample.html):

```
f = randsample(1:numel(v), 1, true, v)
```

What this does is take one random number from the vector `1:numel(v)`, with probability distribution as given in `v`. If you want several values, you can change the second parameter to the number of random numbers you want.